# How to do list comprehension in Clojure?

Tags: haskell, clojure, list-comprehension

I am learning Clojure, and I found the solution to find the right triangle problem in a Haskell book using list comprehension making the problem neatly solved:

Finding the Right Triangle

- The lengths of the three sides are all integers.
- The length of each side is less than or equal to 10.
- The triangle’s perimeter (the sum of the side lengths) is equal to
     24.

In Haskell:

```hs
ghci> let rightTriangles' = [ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..10], a <- [1..c], b <- [1..a],
a^2 + b^2 == c^2, a+b+c == 24]

ghci> rightTriangles'
[(6,8,10)]
```

Is there such an elegant list comprehension solution in Clojure?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Clojure has `for` syntax:

```
(for [ c (range 1 (inc 10))
       a (range 1 (inc c))
       b (range 1 (inc a))
       :when (== (+ (* a a) (* b b)) 
                 (* c c))
       :when (== (+ a b c) 24) ]
  [a b c])
```

Answer (score 10):

```
(for [c (range 1 11)
      a (range 1 c)
      b (range 1 a)
      :when (and (= (+ a b c) 24)
                 (= (* c c) (+ (* a a) (* b b))))]
  [a b c])
```

You can also improve performance a fair bit by inserting `:let [c2 (* c c)]` in between the `c` and `a` bindings, and then use `c2` in the `:when`, to avoid squaring `c` more often than necessary.

Clojure's `for` is basically do-notation for the list monad, with `:when` acting like `guard`, and `:let` acting like `let`. There's `:while` too, but I don't know what haskell thing that corresponds to.

Comment: `:while` doesn't correspond to anything in particular in the list monad. It'd correspond to some other monad, though. Perhaps a [split monoid](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-extras-0.3.3.3/docs/Data-Monoid-Split.html).

Comment: Either this or the accepted answer has an off-by-one error (`c` vc `(inc c)`)

Comment: Well, not exactly. The accepted answer is doing the "obvious" thing of searching all a/b/c triples, and that's fine. This answer makes the observation that for positive solutions to a^2 + b^2 = c^2, it is necessarily the case that c is greater than either a or b, and for integral solutions that b!=a, so there's no need to search triples with repeated values. I think that's fine too; neither answer needs to be fixed.